# How to mass logout all users in pyramid

Tags: pyramid

I use a pyramid and i need logout all users from my site. Currently i cant find any place where are sessions wrote. There is nothing written in pyramid documentations about this situation so is any way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the authentication backend you're using. If the backend stores the session somewhere, you can just clear that somewhere.

If you're using a backend that stores the session in a cookie, like `AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy`, then the cookie is signed with a secret that present in your configuration. Changing this secret would invalidate all cookies, effectively logging out all users.

Answer (score 0):

Change your [session factory](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/narr/sessions.html) settings, such that [`request`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/glossary.html#term-request) object return the [`session`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/api/request.html?highlight=request#pyramid.request.Request.session) after calling its [`session.clear`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/_modules/pyramid/interfaces.html#ISession) method.